# Scroll image up from bottom [CSS, Jquery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to have the image at the bottom of the screen scroll up when the user scrolls down to cover the nav bar and text at the top of the page, which should stay stationery.

Can this be done in css or will jQuery have to be used?

HTML:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans:300,400,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="col-25">
            <img id="logo" src="images/logo-black.svg">
        </div>
        <div class= "col-50">
            <ul class="main-nav">
                <li class="main-nav-link">
                    <a href="Link" class="main-nav-text">HOME</a>
                </li>
                <li class="main-nav-link">
                    <a href="Link" class="main-nav-text">WORK</a>
                </li>
                <li class="main-nav-link">
                    <a href="Link" class="main-nav-text">SERVICES</a>
                </li>
                <li class="main-nav-link">
                    <a href="Link" class="main-nav-text">CONTACT</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-25"></div>
    </div>      
    <div class="top-section">
        <div class="top-section-bg">
            <h1 class="splash-text">We Explore Design.</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="first-section">
    </div>
    <div class="second-section">
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
    font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 0;
}
#logo {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 150px;
}
.header {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.col-25 {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
.col-50 {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
.col-33 {
    width: 33.33333%;
    float: left;
}
.col-66 {
    width: 66.66666%;
    float: left;
}
.main-nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;

}
.main-nav-link {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: 40px;

}
.main-nav-text {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 400;
    transition:all 0.3s ease;
}
.top-section-bg {
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
    height: 800px;
}
.splash-text {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 250px;
}
.subtext {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.first-section {
    background-image: url("images/diver.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    height: 500px;
}
.splash-text-mid {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 70px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 100px;
}
.second-section {
    height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: jQuery is needed for this case because you are working with the distance of the user from the top to get a dynamic value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Iago, would you have any tips on how to implement this?

Comment: I didn't understand exactly what image will scroll up. Is the fish image?

Comment: And a standard implementation is get the scroll top distance every time the user scroll the page and increase/decrease based on this value.

Comment: @IagoMelanias jQuery isn't needed. Anything that can be done with jQuery can be done with vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: I didn't say jQuery as the unique library that can be used, i said jQuery thinking about the javascript. In another words, javascript is needed.

Comment: @HouchinM I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but CSS can be used to have different parts of the page scroll at different rates. If you want to have the image on your site display at the top of the screen as soon as the nav bar is outside the viewport, I think you could use this technique: http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/

Comment: Imagine the header and top-section divs are stationary, then allow the rest of the sections to scroll up and cover the section. I think the parallax method may be the way to go...

Comment: Your question cannot depend on live sites to be answerable.